# Uninitialized constant UserFollowerController on access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm getting `uninitialized constant UserFollowerController` when I access this address:

```
user_follower/new?follower_id=igor_martins
```

I suspect that some parameter is wrong, and I've tried to change them but it didn't work.

user_follower.rb:

```
class UserFollower < ActiveRecord::Base
```

user_followers_controller.rb:

```
class UserFollowersController < ApplicationController
```

user.rb associations:

```
has_many :user_followers
has_many :followers, through: :user_followers
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Can you post your routes file? The problem is likely in there.

Comment: hope it should be `user_followers/new?follower_id=igor_martins` `user_followers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the controller name is `UserFollowersController` then the URL should be

```
user_followers/new?follower_id=igor_martins
```

instead of

```
user_follower/new?follower_id=igor_martins
```